# sed or awk for formatting

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have one text file which consists of group of contact numbers with names like below.

```
   sam=12345,john=98765,bruce=67890,jack=54321,nick=23456,noah=67894,vision=65432,thor=98768,tony=89769,cap=90878
```

I want to delete a particular contact **nick**. I can give a input as contact number. By using "sed" i know only to replace the contact number with blank "**sed 's/23456//g' new.txt**"but name still exists as shown below for nick it is causing error in the backend.

sam=12345,john=98765,bruce=67890,jack=54321,**nick=**,noah=67894,vision=65432,thor=98768,tony=89769,cap=90878

Stuck as above. I want to delete along with name without changing the format(name=number,name=number,and so..)by providing only number as input.

Comment: You'll need to remove the name too, which is some non-comma characters followed by an equal sign followed by the digits, followed by a comma. Can you figure out the regular expression given that hint?

Comment: in my scenario i need to use only numbers as input because names are not proper (most of the case misspelled and typo errors as well) so only

Comment: according to your file format, the name cannot contain a comma. My question remains. How do you write "some non-comma characters" as a regular expression?

Answer (score 3):

What this does is `search for the identifying number preceeded by a string that has neither commas nor equal signs [in other words, their name] followed by and equal and replace all with nothing`.

```
sed -r 's/[^,=]+=23456(,|$)//' new.txt
sam=12345,john=98765,bruce=67890,jack=54321,noah=67894,vision=65432,thor=98768,tony=89769,cap=90878
```

Comment: it is perfect.. Thank you tink.. Could you please explain this one

Comment: @narenviru - adding comment to post.

Comment: @tink: What if `nick=23456` is at the end of the line?

Comment: Fair comment @Cyrus ...